# How to paint over a widget default painting?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to temporarily draw a border around specific widgets at a given ocasiation, for this i'm installing an `eventFilter` and painting the border in the `QEvent::Paint`.

This does work when its a Qframe/QWidget, but not when its a `QLineEdit`, `QPushButton`, in these, the border is not visible:

[image]

The border *probably* is being overridden by the widget paint event.
When i change the painter to draw a rect instead of a roundedRect:
`painter.drawRect(widget->rect());`

[image]

In this use case, how I could make things be drawn "above" the widget original painting like its happening on the QFrame?

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Paint)
    {
        QWidget* widget = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj);
        QPainter painter(widget);
        //painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::red), 2));
        painter.drawRoundedRect(widget->rect().adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1), 12, 12);
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindowClass())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFrame* frame = new QFrame(this);
    frame->setGeometry(0, 30, 200, 32);
    frame->installEventFilter(this);
    frame->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue; border-radius: 12px;");
    frame->show();

    QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    lineEdit->setGeometry(0, 90, 200, 32);
    lineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
    lineEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue; border-radius: 12px;");
    lineEdit->show();
}
```

Comment: The problem with using an event filter is that your filter is always called *before* the widget paints itself.  If you can't achieve the result you want with a stylesheet then you'll probably need to create your own derived class(es) that override `QWidget::paintEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[G.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371123/g-m) said:

> The problem with using an event filter is that your filter is always called before the widget paints itself. If you can't achieve the result you want with a stylesheet then you'll probably need to create your own derived class(es) that override `QWidget::paintEvent`.

To add to that, the red border you're painting is being masked by `lineEdit`'s
`paintEvent`. This can be verified using `background-color: rgba(0,0,255,50)`, and the red border will appear.

There is no way to get that border to appear using a `QPainter` in `eventFilter`. As it's impossible to detect when `paintEvent` finishes.

This answer will demonstrate one way to achieve what you're trying to do, by making a small change to the `QLineEdit`'s stylesheet.

Here's the suggested stylesheeet:

```
lineEdit->setStyleSheet("margin: 2px;"
                        "background-color: blue;"
                        "border-radius: 12px;");
```

the added margin depends on the `QPainter`'s pen width, it basically gives the border room to appear by shrinking `lineEdit`.

Here's how it looks:

[image: QLineEdit with custom border from QPainter]

---

**Note:**

There is a gap on the left side, which is one of the side effects of applying a border radius on `QWidget`'s. You can deal with it by customizing `margin-left`, giving it a value of `1px` for example would get a better result, but it's up to you. You can also adjust the `border-radius` to make the background fit the border.

Also, the text cursor won't fit inside the `lineEdit` (or at least it does not look good to me), and that is also because of the border radius. You might be able to get around that by using a custom cursor with a smaller size.